# how can fetch the Date from the Module to index.js

Tags: node.js, express, module

how do fetch the Date from the Module to index.js

the Module is :

```
const User = require("../models/adduser");

module.exports = {

  getUsers: req => {

     User.findOne().then(users => {

       return users;

     });
  }
};
```

the import Module :

```
const { getUsers } = require("../../helper/test");

console.log(getUsers);
```

the console.log is :

```
[Function: getUsers]
```

how can fetch the Date please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `getUsers` is function, you need call it with `getUsers()`,
but if you call `console.log(getUsers())`, you will see `Promise {...}`.
`getUsers` return `Promise`, not value

(if you don't return `User.findOne`, it will be `undefined`)

Second, return value from promise `User.findOne` was unused, you should return it

Your module:

```
const User = require("../models/adduser");

module.exports = {
    getUsers: req=>{
        return User.findOne().then(users=>{
            return users;
        });
    }
};
```

Call it:

```
const { getUsers } = require("../../helper/test");

getUsers().then(users=>{
    console.log(users);
})
```